# Why the output is different between JDK 1.4 and 1.5?

Tags: java, java-5, jdk1.4

I'm running this code with JDK 1.4 and 1.5 and get different results. Why is it the case?

```
String str = "";
int test = 3;

str = String.valueOf(test);
System.out.println("str[" + str + "]\nequals result[" + (str == "3") + "]");

if (str == "3") {
    System.out.println("if");
} else {
    System.out.println("else");
}
```

outputs:

- on jdk 1.4

  ```
  str[3]
  equals result[true]
  if
  ```
- on jdk 1.5

  ```
  str[3]
  equals result[false]
  else
  ```

Comment: String equality is checked with `"3".equals(str)` and not with `==` operator.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the difference between JDK's but your understanding of how `String` comparison works in Java.  Check out the link provided in my previous comment

Comment: to compare object equality in java you have to use `equals` , using == if they are refering to the same object... if they were interned then that's you get true.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I think the question is why the output is different with jdk 1.4 and 1.5.

Comment: @omgeeeee I have rephrased your question - please check that this is what you meant.

Comment: @assylias you're right!! why the output is different with jdk 1.4 and 1.5 ....

Comment: @assylias Aha I got it now

Comment: I tried it myself and to my surprise the outputs are different.

Comment: @assylias This has something to do with interning of strings behavior being different in 1.4 and 1.5. What are your takes?

Comment: @NarendraPathai Both outputs are valid and I can't remember the last time I worked on 1.4 so it is more of a curiosity than a real issue!

Comment: @MadProgrammer: it *has* to do with the difference in the `String.valueOf` implementation of the different JDKs *and* it is **not** a duplicate of the linked-to-question, it's more specific. Reading that other question will certainly *help* understand the answers here, but they don't themselves answer it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer How? Your comparison `if (str == "3")` is invalid and will never likely be equal

Comment: @MadProgrammer: that's true, but there's nothing wrong with trying to understand *why* it produces different outputs (and *why it's wrong to write it that way*). And explaining *why* something is bad in this particular instance helps more than just saying "that's bad, don't do it".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/250475/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/toString-Integer-class), the `Integer#toString` method (which is called by `String#valueOf(int)`) is implemented like this in 1.4:

```
public static String toString(int i) {  
    switch(i) {  
        case Integer.MIN_VALUE: return "-2147483648";  
        case -3: return "-3";  
        case -2: return "-2";  
        case -1: return "-1";  
        case 0: return "0";  
        case 1: return "1";  
        case 2: return "2";  
        case 3: return "3";  
        case 4: return "4";  
        case 5: return "5";  
        case 6: return "6";  
        case 7: return "7";  
        case 8: return "8";  
        case 9: return "9";  
        case 10: return "10";  
    }  
    char[] buf = (char[])(perThreadBuffer.get());  
    int charPos = getChars(i, buf);  
    return new String(buf, charPos, 12 - charPos);  
}
```

That would explain your result because the string literal `"3"` is interned and `"3" == "3"` always returns true.

You can try with 10 and 11 to verify this.

Note: as already mentioned, the javadoc of `Integer#toString` does not say whether the returned string will be interned or not so both outputs in your question are equally valid.

Comment: +1 In Java 7 is different again. You should not depend on behaviour like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is an implementation detail that is not specified by the JLS.

The reference equality operator `==` checks to see whether two variables point to the same actual object, whereas the `equals` method checks to see whether two variables' values are "equal" in some way that may be determined by the programmer.  In this case, it appears that the 1.4 JVM is taking advantage of the fact that `String`s are immutable to reuse the same copy of the string `"3"` when you call `valueOf` and the 1.5 JVM is not. Both options are perfectly legal, and you should not depend on any particular such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**From java 5 string.valueof() is expected to return new string. rather than intern(ed) (shared) string!**

Consider following example

```
    int test = 3;
    String str = String.valueOf(test);
    String str2 = String.valueOf(test);

    if(str == str2)
        System.out.println("valueOf return interned string");
    else
        System.out.println("valueOf does not return interned string");
```

Output in java >=5

```
valueOf does not return interned string
```

But in java 4 output is

```
valueOf return interned string
```

That explains the behavior!

Comment: You are restating what the op had already observed. The question is: why do 1.4 and 1.5 behave differently.

Comment: Because in java 5 new string is created rather than intern(ed) (shared) string. See the 1st bold line!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "==" operator on operation of String literals, then it depends on the whether the string literal value is present on "String Pool" or not, in your case variable "str" is a string JVM first checks on "String Pool" if it is found then it returns TRUE else FALSE. Try the following code with the intern() method, to make the string literal available on "String Pool"

```
 String str = "";
 int test = 3;

 str = String.valueOf(test).intern();

 System.out.println("str[" + str + "]\nequals result[" + (str == "3") + "]");

 if (str == "3") {
     System.out.println("if");
 } else {
     System.out.println("else");
 }
```

according to documentation for intern() method:
intern() method searches an internal table of strings for a string equal to this String. If the string is not in the table, it is added. Answers the string contained in the table which is equal to this String. The same string object is always answered for strings which are equal.

Well "==" operation is not recommended for string comparison. use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() method().

I tried even in java 1.7 **without** intern() the output is

```
str[3]
equals result[false]
else
```

**with** intern() the output comes to:

```
str[3]
equals result[true]
if
```

This is not the problem of jdk 1.4 and 1.5 this is a "logical error".